# How to create referral links for my app?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have an app which takes data from `firebase` and the data is URLs, These links are in `RecyclerView` in `cardviews`.

So I want users to share these links to friends and reward them for sharing. The links go to different types of websites and some to youtube channels.

So I want to reward users not for clicking the share button but for a friend who clicks the link. The user should be rewarded with points for every friend who clicks the link shared by the user.

So to do this I want to create something like referral links, the link in the `cardview` is `www.google.com` and to create a deep link for the user I take user's id for example `id123`, to make a new link like `www.google.com/id123` so that when the user shares this link and a friend clicks on it, the user receives points.

Links from firebase in cardviews are different. So how can i do this, if there is any example of what I am talking about I appreciate it.

Comment: View this official detailed guide about Dynamic Links, it is quite easy with Firebase dynamic links https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it thought this works for the app installs only

Comment: To use it for each link clicks, you have to achieve this with your web app. That's beyond the reach of android app

Comment: What is a web app, is it a mobile app different from the original one? Because links go to different websites

Comment: I mean your website. You can pass your user id through your website link by using php and reward that user from your web service. I don't think there's any way you can achieve this with android app alone.